# Why not works the search.php file?

Tags: theme-development, search

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

All posts (example) in my custom theme index.php listing:

- Cam on
- Cam off
- Applications
- West side
- Many money

I have a custom theme and custom search.php file. If I search "west", the list:

- **West side**
- Cam on
- Cam off
- Applications
- Many money

I would like see only the "West side" titled post. Why show the another 4 posts?

If I search the "blue", I see all (5) posts. Why? I would like see: 0 posts in list.

The *searchform.php* file:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url ( home_url ( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query (); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

The *search.php* file:

```
<?php

    get_header ();

    if ( have_posts () ) {
        while ( have_posts () ) {
            the_post ();
            print '<p>' . get_the_title () . '</p>';
        }
    }

    get_footer ();

?>
```

The *functions.php* file:

```
<?php

    function search_filter ( $query ) {

        if ( ! is_admin () && $query-> is_main_query () ) {
            if ( $query-> is_search ) {
                $query-> set ( 'post_type', 'post' );
                return $query;
            } else {}
        } else {}

    }

    add_action ( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_filter' );

    function __search_by_title_only ( $search, $wp_query ) {

        if ( strlen ( $wp_query-> query_vars [ 's' ] ) > 0 ) {

            // MySQLi insert the query: $wp_query-> query_vars [ 's' ]

        } else {}

    }

    add_filter ( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );

?>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Your `__search_by_title_only` function is incomplete/empty, that is why you see other results. Perhaps you meant to ask how to restrict search to only titles? Note that the official documentation for the posts_search filter contains a full copy paste filter for searching only by title

Comment: Dear Tom J Nowell, Thanks. It works: function __search_by_title_only ( $search, $wp_query ) { return $search; }